# How to print unnecessary code from a loop?

Tags: java, loops

I am taking data from a text file and taking the first digit of every number. When I try to count the text file it prints:

one: 1
two: 0
three: 0
four: 0
five: 0
six: 0
seven: 0
eight: 0
nine: 0

then,

one: 2
two: 0
three: 0
four: 0
five: 0
six: 0
seven: 0
eight: 0
nine: 0

until it gets its final result:

one: 69
two: 40
three: 36
four: 23
five: 24
six: 16
seven: 14
eight: 14
nine: 11

I am trying to just have the final result so I can move on!/

```
    public static void BenfordPercents(String strLine){


        //System.out.println(strLine);


        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(strLine);
        matcher.find();
        Integer o = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());
        //System.out.println(o);

//      while (Math.abs(o) >= 10){
//          o = o / 10;
//      }

        int firstDigit = o;
        while (firstDigit > 9){
            firstDigit = firstDigit / 10;

        }
        //System.out.println(firstDigit);



        //return Math.abs(o);
        //System.out.println(o);

        if (firstDigit == 1){
            one++;
        }else if(firstDigit == 2){
            two++;
        }else if(firstDigit == 3){
            three++;
        }else if(firstDigit == 4){
            four++;
        }else if(firstDigit == 5){
            five++;
        }else if(firstDigit == 6){
            six++;
        }else if(firstDigit == 7){
            seven++;

        }else if(firstDigit == 8){
            eight++;

        }else if(firstDigit == 9){
            nine++;

        }



        System.out.println("one: " + one);
        System.out.println("two: " + two);
        System.out.println("three: " + three);
        System.out.println("four: " + four);
        System.out.println("five: " + five);
        System.out.println("six: " + six);
        System.out.println("seven: " + seven);
        System.out.println("eight: " + eight);
        System.out.println("nine: " + nine);








    }





}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "printing unnecessary code" ? "print" ? Could you say what you expect as final result ?

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `System.out.println` from `BenfordPercents(String)` method. Make new method called `printResult()`:

```
public static void printResult(){
    System.out.println("one: " + one);
    System.out.println("two: " + two);
    System.out.println("three: " + three);
    System.out.println("four: " + four);
    System.out.println("five: " + five);
    System.out.println("six: " + six);
    System.out.println("seven: " + seven);
    System.out.println("eight: " + eight);
    System.out.println("nine: " + nine);
}
```

Call this method after you've finished all the `BenfordPercents()` call. This will let you see the print only once.

Comment: @DarkV1 He said `I am trying to just have the final result so I can move on!/`. Instead of calling the print each time the processing function is called, he can choose when to print the whole thing, when invoked correctly, he will only see the print once....

Comment: Fixed. You should probably add... call the print method after the BenfordPercents call. When I read your solution it seemed like you were just suggesting calling the method in the BenfordPercent method.. which would have had the same output